# C# Kill all processes not essential to running Windows

Tags: c#, windows-7, dangerous-request

I have an application. If the application is not used in 15 mins it needs to closes all other applications (forced closed) and the timer starts again. I do not want to crash windows 7 doing this. So far I have the following:

```
Process me = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
foreach (Process p in Process.GetProcesses())
{
    if (p.Id != me.Id 
        && p.ProcessName != "winlogon.exe" 
        && p.ProcessName != "explorer.exe"
        && p.ProcessName != "System Idle Process"
        && p.ProcessName != "taskmgr.exe"
        && p.ProcessName != "spoolsv.exe"
        && p.ProcessName != "csrss.exe"
        && p.ProcessName != "smss.exe"
        && p.ProcessName != "svchost.exe "
        && p.ProcessName != "services.exe"
    )
    {
        p.Kill();
    }
}
```

Sadly windows dies (blue screen). Is there any way I could close all the processes for the active use then hopefully Windows may survive.

Comment: Step away from the keyboard...

Comment: Why do you want to kill all those processes?

Comment: Can you explain what you're trying to achieve? I start running this app, then I open Word or FireFox or something, I leave the app neglected, it waits 15 min and then closes Word/FireFox whatever to get me to focus on my work?

Comment: sounds like "annoying virus" code :)

Comment: What user context is the program running in?  Will the user log on and run only this app or is this app executed in a SYSTEM context?  ( This sounds to me something like a kiosk app.)

Comment: @KateGregory  exactly how it should work. It will send you a nice message where you can cancel the shut down.

Comment: @RohanWest this is a public PC that can be used by guests. I need to make sure after someone has used the machine it is at a clean state for the next user

Comment: @jb no virus and I did mark it as dangerous-request :)

Comment: @hova will run as a sytem process but at the moment is running as a user.

Comment: @DavidM If I step away can you help it that all the processes close after 15mins without Windows crashing. Otherwise I need to stay here :(

Comment: Well, if it is running as SYSTEM, why not just have it search for the user attached to the console, and then log them off?  (This will be more difficult than it sounds)

Comment: Hi Sally. I'm curious, what's the `ProcessName` of your application?

Comment: First you should figure out what processes would be safe (in the sense of _not_ crashing the OS) to kill.  That's not something you should be asking us to do for you.

Comment: i have in past tried end shutting down many process in manner.. DO NOT TRY!!! be of full list items of which termination may be possible, iterate

Comment: When you are on Windows 7 (or Vista) the solution would be very simple: Don't run your application with elevated rights (given that your application is not a service).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (p.Id != me.Id
    && !p.ProcessName.ToLower().StartsWith("winlogon")
    && !p.ProcessName.ToLower().StartsWith("system idle process")
    && !p.ProcessName.ToLower().StartsWith("taskmgr")
    && !p.ProcessName.ToLower().StartsWith("spoolsv")
    && !p.ProcessName.ToLower().StartsWith("csrss")
    && !p.ProcessName.ToLower().StartsWith("smss")
    && !p.ProcessName.ToLower().StartsWith("svchost")
    && !p.ProcessName.ToLower().StartsWith("services")
    && !p.ProcessName.ToLower().StartsWith("lsass")
)
{
    if (p.MainWindowHandle != IntPtr.Zero)
    {
        p.Kill();
    }                          
}
```

This seems to be working.

Answer (score 4):

First, set up auto-logon on the public PC.

Then, your program just has to reboot.

Bonus points if you set up [steady state](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg176676%28WS.10%29.aspx) or use a product like [Deep Freeze](http://www.faronics.com/Products/DeepFreeze.aspx), [System Safe](http://www.returnilvirtualsystem.com/), or [Time Freeze](http://www.disk-utilities.com/time-freeze/). Those products even have an option for rebooting the computer to a clean state after a period of inactivity...

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to be safe here is to keep a list of those processes that existed when your application started and exclude those from the kill. However, depending on when your application starts (if it isn't part of the system startup, for example) this may let some applications slip through the cracks. On the up side, it will allow user-mode hooks for devices (such as mouse and keyboard handlers) to continue running, which means the system is still usable after you've killed everything.

You could try [broadcasting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644932.aspx) a [`WM_CLOSE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632617.aspx) message, though I wouldn't be surprised if Windows blocks it. It would only have an effect on processes with visible windows, but that may be sufficient.

A third option is to force a logoff with [`ExitWindowsEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa376868.aspx) that will let the OS handle closing everything. Of course, this will also close your own application and force the user to log on again. If you have an auto-login set up then it *may* log straight back in.

Comment: anwer leads of indication for problem solution of any cost.. many times corrected answers put wrong problem into hands, NO SOLUTION!! look to put out new idea before answer maybe :)

Answer (score 1):

You apperently are killing vital processes needed for windows to function. If you kill those, windows can't recover (as you realized already) and needs to be rebooted.

Comment: many process is must be always run!! answer speaks of why like comment :)